# How to delete a file from dataset view in Foundry?

Tags: file, dataset, delete-file, palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

I have several files in the dataset view:

[image]

How to delete "test.json"? UI seems not to offer such possibility. How to do it using API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using several Catalog API calls:
`startTransaction`
`setTransactionType`
`addFilesToDeleteTransaction`
`commitTransaction`

```py
import requests

token = 'your_token'
fullhost = 'https://your_hostname'
dataset_rid = 'ri.foundry.main.dataset.d2c177b6-5331-4fa1-b09c-bc9b2d18b292'
branch_id = 'master'
file = 'test.json'
headers={
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
}

# Start transaction
response = requests.post(
    url=f'{fullhost}/foundry-catalog/api/catalog/datasets/{dataset_rid}/transactions',
    headers=headers,
    data=f'{{"branchId": "{branch_id}"}}'
)
tx_rid = response.json()['rid']

# Set transaction type (delete)
response = requests.post(
    url=f'{fullhost}/foundry-catalog/api/catalog/datasets/{dataset_rid}/transactions/{tx_rid}',
    headers=headers,
    data='"DELETE"'
)

# Specify the file to be deleted
response = requests.post(
    url=f'{fullhost}/foundry-catalog/api/catalog/datasets/{dataset_rid}/transactions/{tx_rid}/files/addToDeleteTransaction',
    headers=headers,
    data=f'{{"logicalPaths": ["{file}"]}}'
)

# Commit transaction
response = requests.post(
    url=f'{fullhost}/foundry-catalog/api/catalog/datasets/{dataset_rid}/transactions/{tx_rid}/commit',
    headers=headers,
    data='{}'
)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: would you be kind enough to explain the steps with some screenshots.. I tried to copy paste the code and run it via spyder IDE, but it gave me an error at "tx_rid = response.json()['rid']" step. 

I created a dataset by uploading 2 csv files with different trx_id.